# External JS in Django apps best practice

Tags: django

I have two pages that extends a base template. Each page has their own external js which i need to load. For the time being, i have put both of them before closing body tag in the base which means that both JS are loaded on both pages. How is it possible to load specific JS for specific page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it:

**1.** `base.html`

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Foobar</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}

  {% block js %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**2.** `yourpage.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
  <p>your content!</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
  <script src="{% static 'js/foobar.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Invalid block tag on line 93: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Nevermind adding  {% load static %} at the top fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: @want2learncsharp hmm... what django version are you using? because some use `{% load staticfiles %}` and other else use `{% load static %}`, until now I always using `{% load staticfiles %}`..

Comment: I am using 1.11.3

Comment: are you not using `STATICFILES_DIRS` inside the `settings.py`?